# Where can I find the lyrics to the 1981 album "Caramba"?

Tags: lyrics

I am especially interested in the song "Aitho", but it seems only "Habba Habba Zoot Zoot" is commonly available online.

I know the lyrics are included on the rear cover, but I can find no image of sufficient resolution to read it.

**Update:** I have purchased the LP, it's supposed to be in the mail. When it arrives, I shall transcribe the lyrics and share them here for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I received my LP - so here's the full lyrics as printed on the back of the album cover.

[image: Caramba album, front and rear of cover]

```
BLAZTAH 1 (Caramba)


ALI BABA   3.47

Ali baba patheo, thcombe paa tito
Ali baba chineroo, za za paa vito

Terra coro eh, eh oh, oh
A gegga chor e ö er å
Cigarro ro perkelle do
A putella copa ke orzo

Gaah, pillja da dylja
Paah billja dah dodun de dah
Uru guru bi ling a baba dhing e dhing
Apa bullen a gurrka papa

Ali baba . . .

Odelado, dilere lede leda, mama nahma
Popo curra papa kik tappa toy
Ono moninni donquiti xzuij
Papa copa de loba de oy

Mirizazza ooo cari
Marizazza popa pipa pari
Ali baba boba lida larei
La lolita lotta loa loei


SPOTTNJIK   3.13

Djalla strejnevt millo vladja alla pjotr
Zillij bludder azza schlödder lile fjodor
Vladivostok stratzkia vjella drammi ulka
Salmonella vidri schnuska katapulka

Djambalaia streichnee njedre scheibo pravda
Bjellerinja apatruchka tjogga fradga
Bamalama strezza mieni izzi dieria
Da, da spottnjik schnabba bach siberija

Drisjni dra di kosmica, schnabba bach dja spottnijk?
Njadja fraaz da musika mastra stadja jah?
Itzih bitzih njizih zjitt, azta bazta drullja?
bladzi nazi o la la, trattja valda da?

Djoppe tjoppsan rai lai laaaaah
Dvidte vjidde vjitt wot vjit
Bluhndah blllll a spottnjik

Bludder blastja blll blöö
Drr da djzzt sb grr schjt
Oij aij aij gjionkich djalla pjah
Aschta schüssta dtrasch

Glöbaonka -ka-ka-ka gllöbalonka glöh
Lullullullullullull
Yst est åf ett nappa pah
Hyrrda myrrda schlopp -ha

Bla-bla, njet, balop, njet, blah
Bzz, njet, gaah, galonka, njet
Njet, da da tavarish, aah?
Ljajka puschkii skdrrr

Soppskij toppskii, njet, njet
Rullahn bhullan bajdoff, njet
Yrk, njet, tyrk, njet dyhrrc, njet, bah
Njet, njet, njet, njet --- da!


HUBBA HUBBA ZOOT-ZOOT   3.12

Hubba hubba zoot-zoot
Nam!
Ebba obba zat-zat
Nam!
Pa huvee, pa huvee, paa
Pahab huvee paa
A nam nam?
A nam!


EINE FEINE   3.12

Ich war ein schmutzen schnager and der segenbahnen zee
Der himmel meine schuhe sagten unter den kreveh
Das hachensnübel sahne war im strätzelbähne zoo
Die smächen und die drächen ein gefülltener koko

Eine feine kleine nachtmuzik,
Prüpen schnoddaz in der feine nachnmuzik
Olliaah, olliaah, holliaaooiiooio.

Ich slächte und gefächte aber prützen war kaputt
Verschidene gesangen ins enin strützenstrasse strutt
Droschen wonter sochen unter keine meine roh
Die süsen kleine drüssen ein gefülltener koko

Eine feine kleine nachtmuzik . . .

Die gemüse sind gestorben und die sahne sind so schalk
Der pegelton von drachten war ein kleines guten tag
Mit schnabeln umgewickelt immer unter meine schuh
Die böse und gelöze der gefülltener koko

Eine feine kleine nachtmuzik . . .


FIDO   3.25

Fihdoooooooooooo
A boogi-woogi doggi-doggi
Fihdoooooooooooo
Ah rumba
Fihdoooooooooooo
A.doggi
Fihdoooooooooooo
Boogi: doggi
A boogi-woogi doggi-doggi
Boogi-woogi doggi doggi
Booggi woogg

Bogga wogga wogga dansante!!!



BLAZTAH A (Caramba)


AITHO   3 41

Ha-ta khai, tha- bah saii
Paii !!!!
Zahgga dahgga ahgga dai hai
Paii !!!
Mmmmmmmmmmm?
Zagga dai?
Paii !!!
Zaggah!
Paii !!!
Zahga zagai
Paii !!!
Ohto mhotho!
Mmmmmmmmmmm?

Lemmah de tyfe sahti maht ah
Kuhlyp ut omehde hall
Belkjon de frestel sypp sypp
Datgerlap fruj fdink llim

Vlinkrtes dviv vbutr aas
Sossar oh phack slashltr
Mülta e zyhlta eh ritz
Havslret utt bar delkopp

ANNA KAPOEH   4.15

Homo kuae haea mi kaawaii?
Kapuchinae anoie hawaii!
Loa leola kaluha i kanel
Poloeena e molena i ha feel?

Anna kapoae pue, anna maila wainae hu wailah
Maia puha hu mena i ha lai?

An aloae melena i a kuu
Hoaenue kaweiloee a hoo
Ko ko moane, aha, walia laai
Nanni nania pahuuve i a paai!

Anna kapoae pue . . .
Papa huamei a mama i alei
Toi tooki paia separei
A hyeena i papaya i aiö
Ena aoåäeuiyö


DONNA MAYA   3.20

A homme mamma, aum amma
Ah, o-o-o-oh mm, aha
Donna, donna — fehlebabbah
Jum-jum pt-pt o la la

Bah huddo a muddoh
A huligahna huligahna
Bahlooba golonca
A donna maya boom, boom, boom

A hush hush hush a tipp tapp thipp
Bolooba sussa, blip blop bhlip
A blip blipp blopp
A boom boom boom boom boch kautt ! ! ! !

Ha ha ho ho hi hi hehe höhö


AHLLO   2.51

A namma nam, nih nam, ah rhullan bhullan bahjdoff
Dahmma dam dih damm ah jhamm mamma hajdoff
Ah damma dam?
Ah dhumma dhum!
Ah dhemmah dhemmm?
Ah dhym ah dhym!
Ad dö, dhö, dö, dhö, dhö, dhö? döh! dhö?

Ah hullham bull, blipp ahmphull
Ah dhö, dhö: dhöh!
Ah mullan mull
Eh, schwiddevhitd ah kong kang kong kong kong king


CARHUMBA   3.12

Stupido carampah tai
Stjupido caramski skjaj

Sill i dill eh wilie bhilli doff
Zollo dhollo vollo bhollo boff
Ürans thürans lührahns ayatoll
Ha tah kaa tha ohtto bhotto boll

Stupido carampa pah
Stupido caramba bah

Unkan stucan khotte ah die das
Yioppe toppe mhoppe, oder was?
Ahsko tasco fjiasco jazz ko-ko
Rhullan bhullan mhullan blaff ho-ho

Ebba obba zat pah huvee zoot
Ha tah kaa tha ihto ohtto mhott
Rhullan bhullan bajdoff n-n-njet
Tutti frutti capochinsphagehtt


-----


CARLOS IH LURA, ahllo
ZOLTAN ZULL, violotta
DR FRITZ HÖFNER, baribasso
TUDOR LUDOR, batterie
ABDULLA PRESLEY, tomba
ZINGO ALLAH, prutto
IHTO AHMIN, pahuvee
GASTON EL TON YON, pianissimo
KING NAM, a nam
CLAPTON COMBO, gitaronimo
KING KONG, tango
HAZZE KAMIKAZE, teknico del son
GIORGIO MARTINI, producto



Recordeli pour STUDIO GARAGE DE GARBAGE
Picturella par BENGTO HOO
Coloretta par cartong: TORSK PROD
Ⓟ & © 1981 TRASH RECORDS

S|B TUMBA SWEDEN

TRASH RECORDS
PECUNIA NON OLET
DOMESTIC PROD.
TRALP 1
```

(I am pretty certain that my spell checker now hates me.)

Huh. This didn't occur to me 30 years ago, but I wonder: might "Giorgio Martini" even be an alias for Moroder?

Comment: Oh yeah, and by the way: _"Pecunia non olet"_ ~ _"Money doesn't stink"_

Comment: "GIORGIO MARTINI, producto" is most likely alluding to famous producer George Martin

Comment: The transcription reveals the band's Swedish heritage; some of the words are Swedish, or rendered as e.g. Slavic languages would be transcribed into Swedish.